# Latest selected directory as default directory in QFileDialog

Tags: qt, directory, qfiledialog

How can I set latest selected directory as the default directory in QFileDialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should store last selected directory in some variable and use it during next call of `QFileDialog::`[`getOpenFileName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#getOpenFileName):

```
QString path = "/";
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open file", path);
path = QFileInfo(fileName).path();

// default directory will be directory from previous call
QString anotherFilename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open file", path);
```